# Reading a JPEG file from a BLOB (container) field from Filemaker using PHP and ODBC limited to 255 caracters

Tags: php, odbc, filemaker

I am writing a windows php 5.3.5 intranet website to interface a filemaker pro 11 database server.
I use the 11.3.81.0 filemaker odbc driver version.
I want to retrieve image file that are stored in JPEG format. Following the filemaker documentation i execute the following request :
**SELECT GetAs("PhotoA", 'JPEG') AS PhotoA FROM MyTable**
but i only get a string limited to 255 caracters.
How to exceed this limit ?

Comment: where is this in the documentation? Where have you put this SQL query? Is the field you are saving to a container field?

Comment: 1)I read it in http://www.filemaker.com/support/product/docs/11/fms/fm11_odbc_jdbc_guide_en.pdf pages 40/41 (2) the SQL query is executed through a pdo statement with a pdo odbc connexion (3)Yes the field is a container field

Answer (score 2):

You need to use GETAS to return the contents of a container field

SELECT Company_Brochures FROM Sales_Data
SELECT GETAS(Company_Logo, 'JPEG') FROM Sales_Data.

Where "JPEG" is the format of the image File.

There are bunch of possible Formats you can use that are listed here on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724415/filemaker-getas-how-to-display-container-field-on-webpage)

I believe that FileMaker always stores a JPEG version of an image along with what ever other format you put in it.  So you can always use JPEG to get it out.